# C functions requiring explicit call to free()

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, free

I would like to know all the C standard functions that uses malloc() internally and returns a pointer to the newly allocated block of memory. AFAIK there is:

- strdup()
- getcwd()
- get_current_dir_name()

Is that it?  I am writing a complex parser that will change all C raw pointers to more elaborate C++ smart pointers and I need to know where this can't be done automatically.

Comment: The `getcwd` is specified (in the POSIX specification) to *not* allocate memory. See [this official `getcwd` reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getcwd.html).

Comment: **Why do you ask?** and why do you want some exhaustive list of functions related to heap allocation?

Comment: Because I am writing a complex parser that will change all C raw pointers to more elaborate C++ smart pointers and I need to know where this can't be done automatically.

Comment: A good example of a difficult API to automate is the Posix version of `scanf`, which allows string conversions to be optionally modified by the assignment-allocation character `m`, which will automatically allocate a buffer of the correct size, storing its address in the corresponding argument which must be a `char**` rather than a `char*`. Since the format string is a function argument, not necessarily a string literal, there will be cases where correct detection will be speculative.

Comment: Ah-ha. %m is a GNU extension?

Comment: @philbouchard: as i said, it is a **Posix** extension. Glibc implements it, but so does the freebsd libc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list is rather correct, but `strdup` and `getcwd` is POSIX (not standardized in C99), and `get_current_dir_name` is GNU (not even POSIX).

You'll find other functions returning some heap-allocated data.

But you always should **read the documentation of some function before using it**. It will tell you if the returned value is heap allocated (and who and how should it be released).

Some functions take an address of pointer and might change it. For example [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) (POSIX) or [asprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) or [open_memstream(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/open_memstream.3.html) (and some allocation could even happen *later*).

BTW some standard functions like `fopen` are probably using heap-allocated memory (which get freed at `fclose` time).

Likewise, for your own libraries, document them well enough to tell notably who is responsible of `free`-in g (or destroying otherwise) every heap-allocated pointer.  Even for your own private functions, document that in comments.

Automatizing the detection of functions related to dynamic heap memory allocation is difficult and could be impossible to do reliably in the general case (see [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice's_theorem)), so makes an interesting research project.

Comment: `getcwd` does *not* allocate memory.

Answer (score 5):

The list is:

- `malloc`
- `calloc`
- `realloc`
- `aligned_alloc` (new in C11)

None of the functions you listed are standard C.

Comment: Sorry I meant: the list of functions that uses malloc() internally and returns a pointer to the newly allocated block of memory.

Comment: @PhilBouchard That doesn't change the answer.

Comment: You seem to be forgetting `aligned_alloc`.

Comment: @rici Not really forgetting, more like never heard of it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

1. [`void* malloc (size_t size);`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/)

> Allocates a block of size bytes of memory, returning a pointer to the beginning of the block.

2. [`void* realloc (void* ptr, size_t size);`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/)

> Changes the size of the memory block pointed to by ptr.

3. [`void* calloc (size_t num, size_t size);`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/calloc/)

> Allocates a block of memory for an array of num elements, each of them size bytes long, and initializes all its bits to zero.